# How to correlate different values in a RegEx with multiple matches with JMeter- Correlation Recorder?

Tags: jmeter, correlation, jmeter-plugins

I have a problem in JMeter that I can't figure out how to solve.

Situation:

- I want to load test an ASP.NET-website.
- bzm - Correlation Recorder used for recording and correlation
- ScriptResource and WebResource have multiple occurrences

Now I used following RegEx to extract the ScriptResource values: <script src="(.+/ScriptResource.+?)". Then I stored the 3 matched values into 3 different variables.  But I can't replace the values in the found order.
Example:
First Match: stored in : AspNet_ScriptResource
Second match stored in: AspNet_ScriptResource_1
Third match stored in: AspNet_ScriptResource_2

The three matches have all different values, can't paste one value into all 3 matches.
So I have to write the value from AspNet_ScriptResource into the first match (matchNr=1).
AspNet_ScriptResource_1 into second match (matchNr = 2) and
AspNet_ScriptResource_2  into third match (matchNr = 3).

But in the Correlation Rules (in the Correlation Recorder) in the "Correlation Replacement" section, there is no option to choose in which matchNr to write.

[Correlation Recorder: Correlation Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Lkay.png)

I tried to use a BeanShell Preprocessor with a for-loop but I only found a way to write in the logs, not in the response body.

Is there a way to solve this with the Correlation Recorder plugin? If not, what options do I have to handle such a scenario?

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can raise an enhancement request for the bzm - Correlation Recorder via [JMeter Plugins support forum](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins) or if you're a BlazeMeter customer and need this piece of functionality asap - you can [open a support ticket](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket) for implementation of the feature.

Currently it seems that the Correlation Recorder expects you to provide a regular expression either with the unique match or you will have multiple substitutions with the same value.

With regards to Beanshell approach:

1. You can substitute response data, but not with the PreProcessor, you need to do this via the [PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) using [`prev.setResponseData()` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setResponseData-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting
3. If you need to change **request** data, not the response data, you can do this via [`sampler.getArguments()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#getArguments--) function